# Get Product Attribute into Order Confirmation Email

Tags: attributes, email, magento2.2.7

I'm currently attempting to override the following file in order to add the `color` attribute to the Order Confirmation Email:

```
vendor/magento/module-sales/view/frontend/templates/email/items/order/default.phtml
```

Under the "sku" line, I've created an additional line to display the `color` of the product (this is the only change I've made to the file):

```
<p class="product-name"><?= $block->escapeHtml($_item->getName()) ?></p>
<p class="sku"><?= /* @escapeNotVerified */  __('SKU') ?>: <?= $block->escapeHtml($block->getSku($_item)) ?></p>
<p class="color"><?= /* @escapeNotVerified */  __('Color') ?>: <?= $block->escapeHtml($block->getColor($_item)) ?></p>
```

Having tested the email, I can see the label "Color" being output, However it's not returning the actual value.

Comment: what was your eventual code please... trying to use the below answer but it's still not working for me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Item object has a product property that you can retrieve by

```
 $productcolor = $_item->getProduct()->getAttributeText('color');
```

Make sure that $_item is instance of `Magento\Sales\Model\Order\Item`

Comment: This appears to output a value now, but the value is a number instead of the actual color. I've tried a couple of different attributes with similar results.

Comment: Update getData to getAttributeText (or mention the difference) so I can accept answer.